# What's the need for `index` inside `[index: number]: string;`

Tags: typescript

I'm reading about [Indexable Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) here, and the following example is given:

```
interface StringArray {
    [index: number]: string;
}

let myArray: StringArray;
myArray = ["Bob", "Fred"];

let myStr: string = myArray[0];
```

I don't really understand why we need `index` here:

```
[index: number]: string;
 ^^^^^
```

It seems that I can use any name there and it will work, for example:

```
interface StringArray {
    [foo: number]: string;
}

let myArray: StringArray;
myArray = ["Bob", "Fred"];

let myStr: string = myArray[0];
```

I've also seen the following example:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: {[propName: string]: SimpleChange}): void {
    console.log('Changes', changes);
}
```

which as I understand uses some kind of inline indexable type declaration:

```
{[propName: string]: SimpleChange}
```

with `propName` instead of `index`.

Comment: don't slap me too hard if i'm wrong, but this is what i understand: this is only a 'signature' for the index, the name is not that important, but is necessary for the syntax to be understood as a type declaration. If we used `string` only, it could be a variable name or a type, no way to tell. With `string: string`, there is no ambiguity about what is the type.

Comment: @Kaddath, yeah, it could be a signature, but to me `interface StringArray {
    [number]: string;
}` seems fine too. Just want to make sure this name is there for readability only

Comment: it seems that `number` written alone could be also a variable that you are asking to replace by the actual value.. i'm interested in having a confirmation too ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to keep the syntax for type annotations consistent (they are based on type-theory annotations by the way), you need the type to appear after a name.

For example, the following is (stupid) but valid JavaScript:

```
var number = 5;

var arr = [number];

alert(arr[0]);
```

So imagine trying to parse a file and work out whether `[number]` is code or annotation... in the interface it may be pretty easy, but these annotations can appear practically anywhere. And then someone attempts to write an annotation, gets it wrong, and it becomes executable JavaScript.

So for consistency and sanity, type annotations always follow the same pattern...

```
{name}: {type}
```

You can read more about [the link between TypeScript and Type Theory](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BeJbBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA47&lpg=PA47&dq=pro%20typescript%20type%20theory&source=bl&ots=_83cAgHMi8&sig=khL8Qi0P48u9qWGZSw813JCp1Bk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVw7_msMHRAhUsAsAKHQMyAJkQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=pro%20typescript%20type%20theory&f=false).

Comment: thanks, can you point to a relevant resource for _type-theory annotations_?

Comment: @Maximus I have added a link to the original source.

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look. so basically it doesn't matter what name is there, correct? And it seems tha 'index' is the most suitable one